# Как добавить атрибут role с помощью чистого JS

Tags: javascript, html

Помогите пожалуста. Имею такую "непростую"ситуацию. Создал две кнопку с помощью JS, добавил к ним name, но не получается добавить role.

```
var ul = document.querySelector('#ul');
var li = document.createElement('li');
li.className = 'li';
var button = document.createElement('btn');
button.className = 'btn-class';
button.name = 'name';
```

При написании `button.role= 'role';` ничего не добавляется.

Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.className = 'btn-class';
button.setAttribute("name", "name");
button.setAttribute("role", "role");

console.log(button);
```

Comment: Спасибо братан, то что надо!